# How to Sort a Nested List of strings

Tags: java, list, sorting, nested-lists, comparator

I want to sort the list by values in the list. I want to do multisorting based on few parameters in the list. Providing sample example how data looks like.

***Note:** I don't have feasibility to convert `List<List<String>>` into a list of objects.*

```
List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add("Siva"); 
list1.add("20");
list1.add("Hyd");
list1.add("TA");
list1.add("India");  

list2.add("Suresh");    
list2.add("22"); 
list2.add("Banglore");
list2.add("KA");  
list2.add("India");

list3.add("Ramesh"); 
list3.add("24");
list3.add("Chennai"); 
list3.add("TN");
list3.add("India");

data.add(list1);
data.add(list2);
data.add(list2);
```

I want to do multi sorting based on `name`, `age` and `city`.

It's just **sample data**. List of lists is **dynamic**. Sorting parameters will also change sometimes.

I want to do sorting on a list of lists of strings only.

Expected Output: `List<List<String>> sortedData`

Comment: `I don't have feasibility to convert data in to list of object` -> yes you do. Also you need to define an expected output. other wise there is no goal. And at last, you  need to put in some effort.

Comment: I want to do multi sorting base on name,age,city. Output also should be list of list of strings only. Inside list order should be changed base on multi sorting

Comment: @SatishJajimoggala, well, you are only passing `String` into `List`. if you want to sort based on `name,age,city`, you need to create custom POJO & then sort .

Comment: Sorting age by a String will not work as you expect. With strings, `"100"` is less than `"20"`

Comment: Yaa I can understand.. What ever I have provided its just sample data.. List  of list of Strings data dynamic. Sorting parameters also will change sometimes

Comment: All lists are expected to be of equal size or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Solution by Maintaining your Structure

If you can't really create a class wrapping the data in your nested `List` (for whatever reason), you could use the collection stream and define the `sorted` operation's logic as follows:

```
List<List<String>> listRes = data.stream()
        .sorted((x, y) -> {
            int res = x.get(0).compareTo(y.get(0));  //Comparing by name
            if (res != 0) return res;
            res = Integer.valueOf(x.get(1)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y.get(1))); //Comparing by age (numeric value)
            if (res != 0) return res;
            return x.get(2).compareTo(y.get(2));  //Comapring by city
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Link to test the code above:

https://ideone.com/RhW1VI

##### Alternative Solution

However, as it has been pointed out in the comments, a better approach would be to create a custom class representing your data in the nested `List`. Perhaps a simple record if you're using Java 14 or later with a factory method to retrieve an instance of your class from a nested `List`.

Then, with a stream you could map each nested list to your custom class and sort it with a `Comparator`.

Here is a snippet of the implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> data = /* ... your initialization ... */

        List<MyClass> listSorted = data.stream()
                .map(list -> MyClass.createMyClass(list))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getName).thenComparing(MyClass::getAge).thenComparing(MyClass::getCity))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(listSorted);
}
```

Mapping record

```
record MyClass(String name, int age, String city, String code, String country) {

    public static MyClass createMyClass(List<String> list) {
        if (list == null || list.size() < 5) {
            return null;
        }

        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.name = list.get(0);
        mc.age = Integer.valueOf(list.get(1));
        mc.city = list.get(2);
        mc.code = list.get(3);
        mc.country = list.get(4);

        return mc;
    }
}
```

Here there is also a link with both implementations:

https://ideone.com/UK9trV

Comment: Creating custom class will not work in my case

Comment: @SatishJajimoggala look at the first solution and the link I've posted. There's also a solution by maintaining your nested lists as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

In order to impose the order of lists inside a nested list need to define a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

As you've said that contents of the list will can't be predicted in advance, I assume that nested lists might be of arbitrary size and their sizes might not be equal.

A comparator that can handle such case might be written like that:

```
Comparator<List<String>> listComparator = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
        int limit = Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            int localResult = o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i));
                    
            if (localResult != 0) 
                return localResult;
        }
        return o1.size() - o2.size();
    }
};
```

In order to sort the list, you can apply method `sort()` on it (*available with Java 8+*) which expects a comparator:

```
data.sort(listComparator);
```

And you can make a defensive copy of the list *before* applying `sort()`, if its initial order might be useful for you:

```
List<List<String>> initialOrder = new ArrayList<>(data);

data.sort(listComparator);
```